# I have an object with some names as keys, each key has an array of skills, I have to return a new object with skills as new keys and old keys as array

Tags: javascript, object, key, javascript-objects

I have an object like this one

```
const list = {
    jhon: ['js', 'java'],
    sara: ['js', 'python'],
    andy: ['ruby', 'js', 'java'],
    sean: ['python', 'ruby']
}
```

and I have to modify it to show this

```
newList = {
    js: ['jhon', 'sara', 'andy'],
    java: ['jhon', 'andy'],
    ruby: ['andy', 'sean'],
    python: ['sean', 'sara']
}
```

I have tried many ways with no success, thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this result using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Since `Object.entries` will return an array of `[key, value]`. Then inside reduce you can set the property of an object (in this case `acc`) using forEach.

```js
const list = {
  jhon: ["js", "java"],
  sara: ["js", "python"],
  andy: ["ruby", "js", "java"],
  sean: ["python", "ruby"],
};

const result = Object.entries(list).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const [key, values] = curr;
  values.forEach((lang) => {
    if (acc[lang]) acc[lang].push(key);
    else acc[lang] = [key];
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

You can make the above code succinct

```js
const list = {
  jhon: ["js", "java"],
  sara: ["js", "python"],
  andy: ["ruby", "js", "java"],
  sean: ["python", "ruby"],
};

const result = Object.entries(list).reduce((acc, [key, values]) => {
  values.forEach((lang) => (acc[lang] = [...(acc[lang] ?? []), key]));
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over `Object.keys` for each key, and then iterate over the array to insert values in `result` object i.e.

```js
const initial = {
    jhon: ['js', 'java'],
    sara: ['js', 'python'],
    andy: ['ruby', 'js', 'java'],
    sean: ['python', 'ruby']
}

const result = {}

Object.keys(initial).forEach((person) => {
    initial[person].forEach((language) => {
        if (!Array.isArray(result[language])) {
            result[language] = []
        }
        result[language].push(person)
    })
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code and get the result you want:

```
 const list = {
        jhon: ['js', 'java'],
        sara: ['js', 'python'],
        andy: ['ruby', 'js', 'java'],
        sean: ['python', 'ruby']
    };

    function getPersonsByLanguegs(lang) {
        var result = [];

        for (var a in list) {
            if (list[a].includes(lang))
                result.push(a);
        }
        return result;
    }
    var newList = {};

    for (a in list) {
        if (list[a].length > 0)
            for (var i = 0; i < list[a].length; i++) {
                newList[list[a][i]] = getPersonsByLanguegs(list[a][i]);
            }
    }
```

[image]