# How to solve my needs with reduce slove my question

Tags: javascript

```
const formatData = (data) => {
    return data.map((item) => {
        let news = {
            ...item,
            isLeaf: item.haveNext ? false : true
        }
        if (item.children && item.children.length > 0) {
            news.children = formatData(item.children);
        }
        return news
    })
}

let arr = [{
    title: 1,
    haveNext: false,
    children: [{
        title: 2,
        haveNext: true,
        children: [{
            title: 3,
            haveNext: true,
        }]
    }]
}]
```

i want to arr  change to
I don't know how to write some code.
Please help me
arr2 = [{
title: 1,
isLeaf: false,
children: [{
title: 2,
isLeaf: true,
children: [{
title: 3,
isLeaf: true,
}]
}]
}]

```
const formatData2 = (data) => {
    return data.reduce((acc, { haveNext, ...rest }) => {
        let news:any = {
            ...rest,
            isLeaf: haveNext ? false : true
        }
        if (rest.children && rest.children.length > 0) {

        //How to write here
        
        } 
        acc = acc.concat(news)
        return acc
    }, [])
}
console.log(formatData2(arr))
```

Comment: your question is unclear. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: do you mean to rewrite `formatData` by `reduce`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is `reduce` version, but it actually does not reduce anything. `Array.map` is better choice for this use case.

Btw, your `isLeaf` & `haveNext` are literally incorrect, I suggest to check `children` instead.

Documentation [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) [zh-CN](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const formatData = (data) => data.reduce((acc, {children, ...item}) => {
    let news = {
        ...item
    };
    if (children && children.length > 0) {
        news.children = formatData(children);
        news.isLeaf = children.length === 0;
    } else {
        news.isLeaf = true;
    }
    acc.push(news);
    return acc;
}, [])

const arr = [{
    title: 1,
    haveNext: false,
    children: [{
        title: 2,
        haveNext: true,
        children: [{
            title: 3,
            haveNext: true,
        }]
    }]
}]

console.log(formatData(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function to get the results you need.

```js
let arr = [{
  title: 1,
  haveNext: false,
  children: [{
    title: 2,
    haveNext: true,
    children: [{
      title: 3,
      haveNext: true,
    }]
  }]
}];

function loop(arr) {

  // `map` over the array
  return arr.map(obj => {

    // Destructure the properties from the each array object
    const { children, haveNext, title } = obj;

    // If there is a "children" property create a
    // new object but call the function again with the children
    // and change the haveNext prop to newLeaf
    if (children) {
      return {
        title,
        newLeaf: haveNext,
        children: loop(children)
      };
    }

    // Otherwise just return the updated object
    // (haveNext to newLeaf)
    return { title, newLeaf: haveNext };

  });

}

console.log(loop(arr));
```

Additional documentation

- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: I've written it in the map method, but I want to use the reduce method to solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: If your code is working (which you should have mentioned) why the need to use reduce?

Comment: I want to learn the reduce method because I think it is very functional

Comment: It's probably not best suited for this type of question though where `map` is the much better method to use. If you do a [search for `reduce` on this site along with `group and object`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67803570/how-do-i-group-objects-by-key-and-modify-the-array-the-reduce-function-returns) (for example) you should get a feel for it.